# How to copy all subcategories to another category

Tags: php, modx, modx-evolution

I'm working with MODX Evolution 1.0.14. I need to copy few subcategories to another category, how should I do this?

I need to copy [those pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CJIg.jpg) (blue line) to [this place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bHgq.jpg) (blue dot).

I think this is possible just with some custom php-script which will select all pages I need and insert it with another `parent` value.

Answer (score 0):

In MODX Evolution, the fastest way is to run a SQL query directly in phpmyadmin. The code below is for Revolution, but with some minor changes it will work for Evo. I don't know the name of the site_content table in Evo.

```
UPDATE `modx_site_content` SET  `parent` = 765 WHERE `parent` = 1
```

You can build in some extra security so that only resources with a certain template are changed:

```
UPDATE `modxt_site_content` SET  `parent` = 765 WHERE `parent` = 1 AND `template` = 5
```